# In html, if you have a <textarea> being continually appended to (by an ajax call) how do you keep the scroller from being autoscrolled on new data?

Tags: html, ajax

so if you add an textarea to your html page and have some type of continuous output being produced into that text area. The scroll bar keeps scrolling to the top. This will keep you from scrolling up and down manually. How do you keep an textarea from autoscrolling like this when new data enters the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

This is off the top of my head, 
but if you are appending to the textarea with, say, jquery, then something like this should work:

```
var scroll = $('textarea').scrollTop();
$('textarea').append("yourcontent").scrollTop(scroll);
```

If I've understood what you need, this will return to the scrollTop of the textarea as it was prior to the new content being added - it won't prevent the autoscroll but should be quick enough to make it appear to.

Comment: Well everytime the textarea refreshes (on its 2 second interval) the scroll bar slides back upto the top of the scroller. So if your trying to look at something in specific in the textarea, you will be pushed back up to the top in 2 seconds

Comment: to give a better answer I'd need to see your code - if you can, post a fiddle and I'll take a look ( http://jsfiddle.net )